# Android: Cant copy sub directory of sub directory in assets folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to copy some preloaded content stored in the assets folder of my app to the sdk card. Problem is I cant seem to get hold of the file path to the directory I want to copy. I want to loop through the preloadedcontent folder stored in my assets folder in the project, then copy each folder inside it across to the sdk card. I can loop through the preloaded content file names ok, but get a filenotfound exception when i try to copy the directory across:

```
- Assets/
-- preloadedcontent/
--- 112/
--- 113/
--- 114/
```

---

```
private void copyAssets() {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            String[] files = null;
            try {
                files = assetManager.list("preloadedcontent");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
            }
            for(String filename : files) {
                Log.d("file: ",filename);
                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                  in = assetManager.open("preloadedcontent/" + filename + "/");

                  File outFile = new File(_DirectoryName, filename);
                  out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                  //copyFile(in, out);
                  File f = stream2file(in,filename);
                  copyDirectory(f,outFile);
                  in.close();
                  in = null;
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();
                  out = null;
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
                }       
            }

        }
```

error is on this line assetManager.open("preloadedcontent/" + filename + "/");

Comment: asset folder is readable only

Comment: yes, im not writing to it. Im copying the contents to another location...

Comment: Asset manager cannot deal with subfolders.  I wrote a workaround for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636861/why-is-assetmanger-list-so-slow/12639346#12639346

Comment: Really? guess easiest thing might be to zip up my preloaded content then copy the zip across and unzip it...

Answer (score 0):

That's because `"preloadedcontent/" + filename + "/"` is not a valid file name (due to the trailing slash).
[`AssetManager#open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) requires the name of a single file to open.

Answer (score 0):

if(id.equals("AABA / ABO")){

```
            AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();
            String[] files;

            try {

                files = assetManager.list("aaba");
                List<String> it = Arrays.asList(files);

                for (String string : it) {

                    InputStream ims = assetManager.open("aaba/" + string);  

                    // create drawable from stream                      
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);                  
                    drawable.add(d);

                }               


            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   

        }
```

Comment: Add some explanation to it as well.