# Java LibGDX - Black Screen Appears for a Stupid Long Period Before Loading Screen

Tags: java, libgdx, loading, file-management

I'm creating a game in LibGDX/Java. When the game launches, it loads all the assets in the "assets" folder. Before doing this, it loads an image to use as a loading image while the assets load. This works perfectly fine on Desktop, but when launching on android, a black screen will show for approximately 30 seconds before the loading image draws and the assets begin loading.

My current code is as follows:

LoadingState.java:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    if (!loadedBg) {
        GameManager.getInstance().assetManager.finishLoadingAsset("gui/constant/menuBg.png");
        loadedBg = true;
    }

    Texture background = gameManager.assetManager.get("gui/constant/menuBg.png", Texture.class);    // Set background image

    /* Drawing */
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
}
```

Assets.java:

```
/** Loads all assets from the asset directories */
public void load() {

    List<FileHandle> allFiles = new ArrayList<FileHandle>();    // This will contain all the files in all the subdirectories.

    for(FileHandle dir : assetDirs) {
        allFiles.addAll(FileUtils.listf(dir.path()));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < allFiles.size(); i++) {
        if(allFiles.get(i).name().startsWith("._")) {
        allFiles.remove(i);
        }
    }

    /* Iterate through all the files and load only the png ones */
    for(FileHandle f : allFiles) {

        if(f.name().endsWith(".png")) {             // Found an image file; load it as a texture
        manager.load(f.path(), Texture.class);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Added the FileUtils class
FileUtils.java:

```
/** Returns all files from a directory */
public static List<FileHandle> listf(String directoryName) {
    FileHandle directory = Gdx.files.internal(directoryName);

    List<FileHandle> resultList = new ArrayList<FileHandle>();

    // Get all the files from a directory
    FileHandle[] fList = directory.list();
    resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
    for (FileHandle file : fList) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            resultList.addAll(listf(file.path()));
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Is this a problem with android applications as a whole? Or only LibGDX? I wasn't having this issue earlier in development. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You must be doing something time consuming before the first return of the `render()` method. Can't see enough of your code here to determine what. Is FileUtils from Apache Commons, or is that your own class?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for checking my code, sorry for the delayed reply. I went ahead and added the FileUtils class for you to check out. The render class is what is being shown in the LoadingState.java section and I don't believe anything time consuming is being ran, because if that was the case it would also show a black screen on desktop. In its current state, the black screen only appears on android and not desktop. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that calling `list()` on a directory is very slow on Android due to it reading the files out of a zipped apk ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638956/506796)), and so if your assets directory has very many subdirectories, it is eating up a lot of time.

The easy solution would be to not call your `listf()` method until after the `render()` method has returned once (presumably having drawn your loading screen). But this doesn't address the unnecessary 30 second wait.

Since files in the assets folder are known before compile time, I suggest writing a script that scans the assets folder and creates a text file with all paths listed. You can put this file at the root of your assets directory and read it in your `listf` method to quickly get your list of file paths. [Here's an example script.](https://github.com/cypherdare/SpaceShift/blob/master/desktop/src/com/cyphercove/dayinspace/desktop/DirectoryCataloguer.java) During development, you can set this script to automatically run when you run your Desktop version.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what the issue was. You led me in the right direction